# Php How to convert unicode to russian chacrters

Tags: php, unicode

Here is my string

```
Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ð°Ñ-Ð·Ð¾Ð½Ð°
```

converting this would give

```
запретная-зона
```

how do i convert using php? I tried other Unicode conversion answers.. but none worked

I have tried based on the answers....please see the results...

```
$my_str = "/Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ð°Ñ-Ð·Ð¾Ð½Ð°-chernobyl-diaries-20-q38685478.html";
$encoded = iconv("Windows-1252", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $my_str);
echo $encoded;
echo "<br>";
echo mb_convert_encoding($my_str, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
```

Below is the result...

```
/ÃÂ·ÃÂ°ÃÂ¿Ã‘â‚¬ÃÂµÃ‘â€šÃÂ½ÃÂ°Ã‘-ÃÂ·ÃÂ¾ÃÂ½ÃÂ°-chernobyl-diaries-20-q38685478.html
/?????????-????-chernobyl-diaries-20-q38685478.html
```

anyways to fix this? where am i doing wrong?

Comment: `Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ð°Ñ-Ð·Ð¾Ð½Ð°` this is your original string?

Comment: yes..its my original string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the string `Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ð°Ñ-Ð·Ð¾Ð½Ð°` indeed looks like UTF-8 string `запретная-зона` encoded in Windows-1252:

```
$s = 'запретная-зона';
$encoded = iconv("Windows-1252", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $s);
echo $encoded, PHP_EOL;
// Outputs: Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ð°Ñ-Ð·Ð¾Ð½Ð°
```

Note that we've ignored invalid sequences with `//IGNORE`, because otherwise
conversion is not possible:

```
$s = 'запретная-зона';
$encoded = iconv("Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $s);
var_dump($encoded);
```

This code fails:

```
Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in /home/ruslan/tmp/1.php on line 3
bool(false)
```

As we see, conversion from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 is lossy - we can convert some characters, but some must be ignored. Otherwise, conversion fails.

Obviously, if we try to decode the `$encoded` string back to UTF-8, some characters will be broken:

```
echo iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252//IGNORE", $encoded), PHP_EOL;
// Outputs: запретна�-зона
```

Thus, you need the original text properly encoded using a Russian character set. Only having the original you will be able to convert it to UTF-8 (and back again).

I guess, you see the string encoded in Windows-1252 just because of some automatic conversion, such as browser's character set auto-detection, and the original text is encoded in different encoding. And that's where it is important to know where your string comes from (text file, database, etc.). I can't give better answer, because you haven't put these details into the question. But the idea is to apply the conversion to the original stream of bytes. For instance:

```
$text = file_get_contents('/tmp/file-in-windows-1251.txt');
echo iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $text), PHP_EOL;
```

Note, Windows-1251 (not Windows-1252) is a valid encoding for Russian.

Comment: @YourFriend, again, it is interesting where this string comes from: `$my_str = "/Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ð°Ñ-Ð·Ð¾Ð½Ð°-chernobyl-diaries-20-q38685478.html";`. You don't hard-code it, do you?

Comment: @ Ruslan Osmanov No its not hardcoded... actually iam scraping it from a website...where the url is shown as `/запретная-зона-chernobyl-diaries-20-q38685478.html` when i fetch it is shows `/Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ð°Ñ-Ð·Ð¾Ð½Ð°-chernobyl-diaries-20-q38685478.html`

Comment: @YourFriend, then, assuming that you've downloaded the site code into `$html` variable, and the site is encoded in `Windows-1251`, you can simply `$html = iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $html);`

Comment: @ Ruslan Osmanov thanks for your suggestion.. ya i think This would work.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

As `Universal Cyrillic decoder` says your string is encoded in UTF-8, automatic decryption suggests that your original string is `Windows-1252` encoded, so a back conversion would be sufficient to get back to russian chars.

```
$s = "Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÑ‚Ð½Ð°Ñ-Ð·Ð¾Ð½Ð°";
iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $s), PHP_EOL;
```

otherwise you can use this method

```
mb_convert_encoding($s, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
```

Result:

```
запретна�-зона
```

Comment: make sure you have iconv installed

Comment: On windows php 7.3, mb_convert_encoding gave cleaner results than iconv with the same parameters.
My string was 'ÑÐ¾Ñ€Ñ‚Ð° Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð¸Ð·Ð²Ð¾Ð´ÑÑ‚Ð²Ð°'